# User registration error : Two different values for password in database?

Tags: joomla-3.x, authentication

I tried to register a new user from Joomla frontend, registration was successful plus activation via email was also successful, now when i try to login using the new credentials, i get a error " Username and password don not match or you don't have an account yet "?

**What's interesting?** 
-> when i registered from frontend and set the password to `read` , this value was found in *_users table* `f0bb7564f8c84d1cbdada8dc04493be2`

-> & when i set the password to `read` using `Joomla backend`, this value was found in *_users table* `0edda82c8ad9aa4da0dfe3b64f249c18:dqRwd90MzB21LP8waOjW0XEQzt4LSZoE` and the login was successful?

I AM CONFUSED, WHY TWO DIFFERENT VALUES FOR SAME PASSWORD `read`

[Joomla Version : 3.2]
[PHP Version : 5.4]

Comment: Please add the exact version of your Joomla. 3.2 is likely too broad for this question.

Comment: **THANK YOU ALL! YOU ALL WERE HELPFUL!** *I GOT MY SITE BACK ON BUSINESS*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue with 3.2.0 in particular, especially if the site has been updated from 3.1.*  Although I can't remember exactly, I think it has something to do with the change of password hashing from md5 to bcrypt or the addition of Two factor authentication.

Have you tried "updating to 3.2.3" by installing the update package through extension manager.
Checking the database is updated and then try again?

Comment: can anybody guide me how to change password hashing from md5 to bcrypt??
-- i am afraid to update joomla at this point of time with this problem! :(

Comment: Can you provide exact Joomla version and site history (was it updated/migrated?)

Comment: Hey! i just updated to `Joomla 3.2.4` from `Joomla 3.2.0` and enabled `Two Factor Authentication` and the problem was solved but at the login form it showing another field "Secret Key" , how to remove that?? 

[i left it blank and logged in with username & password only. It worked!] is there anyway to remove that field?

Comment: You don't need to enable two factor authentication.  The update has resolved the issue not two factor auth.  You may now need to resave your users passwords.

Comment: breaking news! now users can login from front-end BUT I CAN'T LOGIN TO MY ADMIN PANEL FROM BACKEND? this is hell! :(

Comment: No need to shout. Have you tried clearing your browser cache and rentering your known admin password.  If that doesn't work, do you know how to edit password in the database?  Thinking about it, why not just try password reset process?

Comment: yep! i cleared the browser cache.plus i disabled the two factor authentication from phpmyadmin , the secret key field is gone but still not able to log in!

Comment: i tried to rest my password but i get an error saying "Superusers can't request password reset"?

Comment: Use PHPMyAdmin to change your password.  You can use: 0edda82c8ad9aa4da0dfe3b64f249c18:dqRwd90MzB21LP8waOjW0XEQzt4LSZoE (read). Then change it once logged in.

Comment: that is due tho the password hash (old one), re-hash it and it will work again

Answer (score 2):

Joomla 3.2.0 had a major bug with password storage which was fixed with Joomla 3.2.1. You issues sounds quite like that.

See http://community.joomla.org/blogs/leadership/1790-update-on-321-and-security-enhancements.html for some more details