# Password problem when a user registers (Akeeba Subscriptions)

Tags: login, akeebabackup, account-password

I'm building a property website using iProperty for the properties and Akeeba Subscriptions to allow users to sign up through the front end.

I have set up two different types of subscription (one where users sign up through the front end to be able to upload and manage their properties; the other is manually created by the admin in the backend, and then the details are sent to the user who can login and maintain a 'Favourites' list).

The problem is that the accounts do not work unless I manually reset the password in the backend. I do not know why this is happening, but what is even stranger is that the front end registration works and then logs the user in and they are able to manage properties, BUT, as soon as they logout, there is no way back in for them unless I manually reset their password in the backend. An example of this is here if anyone wants to spend a minute to see this: red-ferndevelopment.co.uk/OfficeExperts/...iew=level&Itemid=347

I'd be very grateful if anyone has any suggestions?

Many thanks 
Austin

Comment: What version of Joomla and PHP are you using? Also, are you using the latest version of Akeeba Subs?

Comment: Joomla 3.2.0, Akeeba Subscriptions 4.0.1, PHP 5.4.26.... thanks

Comment: is **TWO FACTOR AUTHENTICATION** enabled?

Comment: No both the Google and YubiKey plugins are disabled

Answer (score 5):

You should upgrade to latest version of Joomla 3.2 or to Joomla 3.3
As per [this link](http://alterbrains.com/blog/100-joomla-3-2-passwords-issue-problem-solution) Joomla 3.2.1+ , doesn't have this issue.

If you can't upgrade then you need to change Joomla code (I won't recommend this), and the details are mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Thanks. I had a play around with the system and somehow managed to fix it, not sure how though! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem on my site exactly on **JOOMLA 3.2.0** An update to **3.2.4** and enabling two factor authentication solved it automatically! If you're not able to update right now, try enabling two factor authentication and register a new user via front-end and see whether it works!
and if i am not wrong, this is happening to your site, Have a look at this one : [User registration error : Two different values for password in database?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/751/user-registration-error-two-different-values-for-password-in-database)

Comment: Thanks. I had a play around with the system and somehow managed to fix it, not sure how though! Thanks